# Recognizing encrypted from plaintext

Tags: password-encryption, rncryptor

I am using RNCryptor to encrypt/decrypt (AES256) files for an Objective C project.

I would like my app to ask for a password if the chosen file is encrypted (say, with AES256) or to open it directly if it isn't. Is there a way of recognizing if a given file is encrypted?

Comment: In the general case, no.  Encrypted data is pure random bits, but you can have an unencrypted data file that's essentially that as well.

Comment: Understood. How about something like this: _before_ encryption, I write the encryption key on the first line of the file. Then, when the user gives me the key, the app checks it against the first line of the decrypted file. Only if they match, it returns the decrypted file minus the first line.

Comment: That would sorta work.  Probably should check with the guys at http://security.stackexchange.com/, though.